# how to use Notifications to set up a deeplink?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, deep-linking, android-pendingintent

Sorry this might be a dummy question but I haven't used deeplink before.

I have two apps A and B, and I have to use app A to push an android notification, which has a deeplink url, so when user taps on the notification app B will be launched and will deep link to an activity, say Foo.

So my question is: besides the schema both apps agree on, does app A need to know which activity of app B will be used to receive the intent? In this case it is activity Foo.

The problem I have now is that when I tap on the notification, app B doesn't react.

In app B's manifest, I have added

```
<activity android:name="com.myexample.deeplink.Foo">
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

In app A I have:

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://example.com/item/12345"));
    intent.setFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

ContentRecommendation cr = new ContentRecommendation.Builder()
                    .setContentImage(
                            getContentImageBitmap(contentImage)
                    .setContentIntentData(
                            intentType,
                            intent,
                            0,
                            null)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setText("Dummy Text")
                    .setBadgeIcon(R.drawable.sample_app_icon)
                    .setBackgroundImageUri(background)
                    .build();
final Notification notification = cr.getNotificationObject(context);
```

What did I miss here?
Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to add `pathPatteren=/.*` inside your data tag ?

Comment: [Refer to this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html#adding-filters), the `scheme` and `host` is necessary, app A doesn't need to know which activity of app B will be used to receive the intent. I usually use a hyperlink to jump to other activity. If you use `Notification` you can use the `PendingIntent` to jump. Could you show your `Notification` code?

Comment: Try opening that link from the browser , see if it links to your app or not

Comment: @JoeLv Thanks, I have added my notification code.

Comment: I actually fixed the issue. I had a bug in my code that overwrote the uri to a wrong one, sigh...such a silly mistake. Thanks everyone for helping me!!

Comment: Please either answer your own question and accept the answer, or delete this question. Either will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions and will help others. Thanks!